# How to create a Matrix from an Array in R?

Tags: r

I have a simple array, like:

```
x <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
```

I would like to create a matrix from this array, because those numbers are prices of two stocks.

```
stock A: 10 30 50 70 90 
stock B: 20 40 60 80 100
```

How can I create two columns from this list of prices.

Thank you

Comment: Did you read `help(matrix)` and/or `help(as.matrix)` ?

Comment: Have you tried `matrix(x,ncol = 2)`? Try reading `?matrix`.

Comment: I wrote wrong the prices of the stocks, take a look at STOCK A - B again, I don't think i can use ncol=2, no?

Comment: @Dail Have you tried what is suggested? R fills by columns **not** rows, *unless* you tell it to. `matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)` gives you a matrix where the columns refer to A and B. If you want something different, and not a matrix, then perhaps a list is required. For that, try `split(x, rep(c("A","B"), length(x)/2))` for a start.

Comment: I think the OP wants `nrow = 2`.

Comment: @Roman he does say two columns... but seeing as they got the some of the data wrong originally, that could be an error too...

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the OP actually wants:

```
> matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   20
[2,]   30   40
[3,]   50   60
[4,]   70   80
[5,]   90  100
```

or possibly

```
> split(x, rep(c("A","B"), length(x)/2))
$A
[1] 10 30 50 70 90

$B
[1]  20  40  60  80 100
```

which can be converted to a data frame easily enough...

Answer (score 1):

Just push the vector into matrix

```
matrix(x, ncol = 2)
```

No need to specify the number of rows since that is implicit. See ?matrix

Comment: I wrote wrong the prices of the stocks, take a look at STOCK A - B again, I don't think i can use ncol=2, no?

Comment: Yeah byrow is the thing. Read the help :)